# Passing array of objects among classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Afternoon all,
First question on Stack Overflow -- will do my best to be clear.

I have created an array of objects "Objects2[arraySize]" for a class "Class 2" which must be referenced both in Class 1 and the main() function.

Class1.h

```
class Class1
{
public:
  void parseFunction(several parameters);

private:
  int otherVariables; 
};
```

Class1.cpp

```
#include "Class1.h"

void Class1::parseFunction(several parameters)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
    Objects2[i].someMemberFunction();
  }
}
```

Main

```
#include "Class1.h"

main()
{
  Class2 Objects2[arraySize];    //Arbitrary array size
  Class1 Object1;

  Object1.parseFunction(some parameters);

  for(int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
  {
    Objects2[j].someOtherMemberFunction();
  }
}
```

I have simplified this to the best of my ability, and hopefully to the point of readability. My goal is to be able to access these objects "Objects2[arraySize]" from multiple classes, but am struggling getting the pointers to work. I have intentionally opted to use a fixed array size rather than a vector as an attempt to simplify the code for the time being.

As it stands right now only one class (err, main OR class 1) can access these objects and their functions at a time. I looked into making Class 1 act as a 'pass through' to the functions in Class 2, but that feels hokey. Is there a more elegant way? Any pointers?

Edit: To be clear, I do not have a firm grasp of how objects may be shared among different classes. My goal is to create a large number of these "Objects2[arraySize]" objects (accomplished by creating an array of them), and access them in several different classes. I have researched passing by reference, but can't quite get it right for this array of objects.

Comment: And you don't use `std::array` or `std::vector` because...?

Comment: What is not working with the current implementation ? Everything seems correct to me other than you miss to include `Class2` header in `Class1`. Also, the `Class2::someMemberFunction()` needs to have public access.

Comment: @Mahesh his code's ignoring scope. `Object2` is local to `main` but he wants to use it in `Class1::parseFunction`.

Comment: @greatwolf Isn't OP passing `Objects2` as part of `some parameters` ?

Comment: @Jeffrey wow, don't know why I didn't think to use std::array, but I don't know if that will help to give both main and Class1 access to the class2 objects

Comment: `for(int j = 0, ` looks incorrect btw. Is that just a typo?

Comment: @greatwolf Yes, just a typo. Just an example of how I would like to iterate through the objects.

Comment: Simply declare "Class2 Objects2[arraySize];" inside Class1 and provide a public accessor.

Comment: @Trenin doesn't that effectively make those objects a global variable?

Comment: According to your question you essentially want to access them exactly like a global variable. What's the issue?

Comment: @Arlo012 - no it makes it a member of Class1 with methods to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a specific answer while you are looking for a more generic one, but you could simply include the array as a member of Class1 and provide public access like this.

```
class Class1
{
  public:
    Class2 Objects2[arraySize];
    void parseFunction(several parameters);

  private:
    int otherVariables; 
};
```

In the main program, you can access it as Object1.Objects2. If you don't want it tied to the instance, you could make it a static member.

However, a better way may be to hide the actual member and provide accessors (get/set).  It depends on what you are trying to do.

If you wanted to pass by reference, then you could change your method in Class1 as follows:

```
void Class1::parseFunction(several parameters, Class2& Objects2[])
```

And then pass it in as a parameter from main and reference it in the parseFunction method.

Another method is to include a "Globals.h" file which defines all the things you want accessible everywhere.

Comment: This is really helpful Trenin. I was not aware that it was possible to access objects in that way, i.e. Objects1.Objects2. I'll read over this more thoroughly, but I think this will help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Objects2 resides within "main", so it isn't even possible to access it from a Class1 object as it stands. Some options available to you are to:
(1) Pass the array to Class1::parseFunction.
(2) Store an actual reference/pointer in "Class1".
(3) Make the array global.